# Trabalhando com Entity Framwork e Banco de Dados Sql Express

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, sql-server-express

Tenho uma aplicação com uma conexão ao banco de dados e preciso criar um instalador que contenha o script do banco de dados para que ele seja instalado juntamente à aplicação ou em algum momento simultâneo á primeira execução.
Como criar um instalador por meio do inno setup com o banco de dados associado por meio do Entity Framwork?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/executing-sql-file-form-c-sharp1